# Flags, loops and locks in async code

Tags: c#, locking, async-await

What I'm trying to do is create a 'Listener' which listens to several different Tcp ports at once, and pipes the messages to any Observers.

Pseudo-ish code:

```
private bool _Listen = false;
public void Start()
{
    _Listen = true;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Listen(1);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Listen(2);
}

public void Stop()
{
    _Listen = false;
}

private async void Listen(int port)
{
     var tcp = new TcpClient();
     while(_Listen)
     {
          await tcp.ConnectAsync(ip, port);
          using (/*networkStream, BinaryReader, etc*/)
          {
               while(_Listen)
               {
                   //Read from binary reader and OnNext to IObservable
               }
          }
     }
}
```

(For brevity, I've omitted the try/catch inside the two whiles, both of which also check the flag)

My question is: should I be locking the flag, and if so, how does that tie-in with the async/await bits?

Comment: Why is `Start()` marked as `async`? You're not using any `await` there.

Comment: @svick, you're right, it was an error in my pseudo-ification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should change your return type to Task, not void. `async void` methods are essentially fire-and-forget and can't be awaited or cancelled. They exist primarily to allow the creation of asynchronous event handlers or event-like code. They should never be used for normal asynchronous operations.

The TPL way to cooperatively cancel/abort/stop an asynchronous operation is to use a [CancellationToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx). You can check the token's [IsCancellationRequested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.iscancellationrequested.aspx) property to see if you need to cancel your operation and stop.

Even better, most asynchronous methods provided by the framework accept a CancellationToken so you can stop them immediatelly without waiting for them to return. You can use NetworkStream's [ReadAsync(Byte[], Int32, Int32, CancellationToken)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193669.aspx) to read data and cancel immediatelly when someone calls your Stop method.

You could change your code to something like this:

```
    CancellationTokenSource _source;

    public void Start()
    {
        _source = new CancellationTokenSource();            
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Listen(1, _source.Token),_source.Token);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Listen(2, _source.Token), _source.Token);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _source.Cancel();
    }


    private async Task Listen(int port,CancellationToken token)
    {
        var tcp = new TcpClient();
        while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await tcp.ConnectAsync(ip, port);
            using (var stream=tcp.GetStream())
            {
                ...
                try
                {
                    await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count, token);
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
                {
                    //Handle Cancellation
                }
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

You can read a lot more about cancellation in [Cancellation in Managed Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx), including advice on how to poll, register a callback for cancellation, listen to multiple tokens etc.

The `try/catch` block exists because `await` throws an Exception if a Task is cancelled. You can avoid this by calling ContinueWith on the Task returned by ReadAsync and checking the IsCanceled flag:

```
    private async Task Listen(int port,CancellationToken token)
    {
        var tcp = new TcpClient();
        while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await tcp.ConnectAsync(ip, port);
            using (var stream=tcp.GetStream())
            {
                ///...
                await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count, token)
                    .ContinueWith(t =>
                    {
                        if (t.IsCanceled)
                        {
                            //Do some cleanup?
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Process the buffer and send notifications
                        }
                    });
                ///...
            }
        }
    }
```

`await` now awaits a simple `Task` that finishes when the continuation finishes

Comment: Yeeees, I'll bear it in mind. Maybe I'm unfairly prejudiced against Cancellation tokens, dunno, it feels clunky. And my `Start` *is* pretty much fire and forget...

Comment: How is the token *worse* than the flag or event? (Not to mention that the token is purpose-built and already used throughout the framework). Actually, the source/token design decouples the sender of the cancellation from the receiver

Comment: “`async void` methods can't be canceled” That's not true, you can cancel `async void` method. It's just that the caller has no way of knowing if and when the cancellation actually happened.

Comment: Also, while you're generally right that `async void` methods should be avoided, it doesn't make much difference if you ignore the resulting `Task` anyway. (The only difference is that uncaught exceptions in `async void` will crash the application, but they won't do anything in `async Task` if you ignore the `Task`. This makes `async Task` actually the *worse* choice.)

Comment: @svick, Panagiotis. OK, ok, I'll give it a try :) I guess what I don't like is that it feels like I'm using the exception as part of control flow...

Comment: That's the way `await` works. The token doesn't cause any exceptions. You can call `ContinueWith` after ReadAsync and check whether the task was cancelled

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You can add an "OnlyOnCancelled" option to the continuation if its only goal is to handle the cancellation case.

Answer (score 1):

Some form of Event (such as [`ManualResetEventSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim.aspx)) would be a more obvious choice when you're potentially dealing with multiple threads.

```
private ManualResetEventSlim _Listen;
public void Start()
{
    _Listen = new ManualResetEventSlim(true);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Listen(1);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Listen(2);
}

public void Stop()
{
    _Listen.Reset();
}

private async void Listen(int port)
{
     var tcp = new TcpClient();
     while(_Listen.IsSet)
     {
```

Comment: Slim seems to be for short-lived events: should I be using ManualResetEvent if this is going to be Start/Stopped in 'human' time scales?

Comment: @Benjol - no, I'd use Slim. The primary difference between them happens when the event *isn't* signalled, but in the above, the event is signalled most of the time.

Comment: How is this better than `volatile bool`?

Answer (score 1):

You would probably be better of sticking with RX all the way through instead of using Task. Here is some code I wrote for connecting to UDP sockets with RX.

```
public IObservable<UdpReceiveResult> StreamObserver
(int localPort, TimeSpan? timeout = null)
{


    return Linq.Observable.Create<UdpReceiveResult>(observer =>
    {
        UdpClient client = new UdpClient(localPort);

        var o = Linq.Observable.Defer(() => client.ReceiveAsync().ToObservable());
        IDisposable subscription = null;
        if ((timeout != null)) {
            subscription = Linq.Observable.Timeout(o.Repeat(), timeout.Value).Subscribe(observer);
        } else {
            subscription = o.Repeat().Subscribe(observer);
        }

        return Disposable.Create(() =>
        {
            client.Close();
            subscription.Dispose();
            // Seems to take some time to close a socket so
            // when we resubscribe there is an error. I
            // really do NOT like this hack. TODO see if
            // this can be improved
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Funnily enough, a previous version of this code *did* use UDP and I *did* do Rx all the way through. I might even be able to stop using `Subject` if I go this route...

Comment: I find I very rarely use Task directly in my code. Task is just a degenerate form of RX where you only want a single value returned. Often it's easier to remember the RX version of things. For example wait for 200 milliseconds  ``await Observerable.Interval(Timespan.FromMilliSeconds(200)).Take(1)`` I'm sure there is a direct Task based version but I can't remember it.

Comment: Hm, I just gave it a go, but it got a bit too hairy in the middle (nested Observable.Usings and try-catches) :(

Comment: Post your attempt. Somebody will help :)

Comment: I'll work on it a bit more then post it to CodeReview, probably next week though.

Answer (score 1):

> should I be locking the flag, and if so, how does that tie-in with the async/await bits?

You need to synchronize access to the flag somehow. If you don't, the compiler is allowed to make the following optimization:

```
bool compilerGeneratedLocal = _Listen;
while (compilerGeneratedLocal)
{
    // body of the loop
}
```

Which would make your code wrong.

Some options how you can fix that:

1. Mark the `bool` flag `volatile`. This will ensure that the current value of the flag is always read.
2. Use `CancellationToken` (as suggested by Panagiotis Kanavos). This will make sure that the underlying flag is accessed in a thread-safe manner for you. It has also the advantage that many async methods support `CancellationToken`, so you can cancel them too.